# how to publish vendor from package Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I've my custom Laravel 5.4 package, and i want to publish the vendor packages located into my package, this is my code (PackageServiceProvider.php):

```
$this->publishes([
  __DIR__.'/../vendor/soundasleep' => public_path('soundasleep'),
], 'html2text');
```

but when i run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=html2text` the vendor is published into **public** folder and i want to be published into my application vendor, because when i tried `use \Html2Text\Html2Text as html2text;` into my package `routes.php` i got `class Html2Text\Html2Text not found`.

this is my composer :

```
"require": {
    "soundasleep/html2text": "~0.5"
}
```

[**I wondered if there is some thing like** `vendor_path` ]

so please if someone has any idea i'll be very appreciative.

Comment: This has nothing to do with where your package is located, this is your composer config. Could you post your composer file for this package?

Comment: The point of publishing your config etc is to create the files so that the user can easily make configuration changes/overrides themselves. You should write your package to use your own configuration/files as default and map the user's changes over the top. Nothing in the vendor directory should ever change.

Comment: i add my composer

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to register your package in `config/app.php` . Add it to the providers array.

`Html2Text\Html2Text\PackageServiceProvider.php::class,`

Third party packages should publish config files into the config directory. In your service provider, you publish it to the public folder `public_path('soundasleep')`.

Change it to `config_path('soundasleep')`.

Comment: i am already include my package to config/app.php , Html2Text\Html2Text is a package in my composer, i update my question

Comment: Did you do composer install ?

Comment: yes of course inside my package i do composer update but when i tried to use it i got class Html2Text\Html2Text not found

Comment: Where is your package? is it in the vendor directory?

Comment: open composer.lock not composer.json and search for your package name. If it's not there, that's mean it's not loaded by composer.

Comment: nop is a Laravel package (packages/dev/mypackage) and inside this i have my composer.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148784/discussion-between-hamoud-and-mohammed-hassar).